# How can I implement Material 3 dynamic colour in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm writing a Flutter app with Material 3 and I don't really know how to implement material colour to replace the primarySwatch for example, any help?

By the moment I have the dynamic colour library installed with flutter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the primaryColor attribute of the MaterialApp widget